# Optimal control problem with boundaries depending on control

Tags: boundary-value-problem, optimal-control, maximum-principle

I have a relatively standard optimal quadratic control problem on infinite horizon :
$\int_0^\infty (R-u)^\top (R-u) + C(t)^\top u~  dt $ subject to $\dot R = kR - k u $ but with one specific. The differential equation for $R$ above  is artificially constructed  from integral
$$
R = \int_x^\infty ke^{k(x-t)} u(t) dt 
$$
where $k$ is positively definite matrix. Here $R,u$ are $n$-dimensional vectors.
That means that $R(0)=\int_0^\infty k e^{-kt} u(t)dt$, $R(\infty)$ is somehow $u(\infty)$ if $u$ has a limit. So my boundary conditions for $R$ are determined by $u$.  $u$ is in interval $[-1,1]^n$.
Let us setup Hamiltonian
$$
H = R^\top R + 2 R^\top u + u^\top u + C(t)^\top u + \lambda^\top (kR-ku) 
$$
and optimal $u$ in terms of $R$ and $\lambda$ from
$$
\min_{|u|_\infty<1} (  R^\top R + 2 R^\top u + u^\top u + C^\top u +\lambda^\top (kR-ku))
$$
will be
$$
u = \min(1,\max(-1,(-C(t)+k\lambda - 2R)))
$$
The equations will be :
$$
\dot R = k R  - k u = \frac{\partial H}{\partial \lambda}
$$
$$
\dot \lambda = -2R + 2u - C(t) - k \lambda= -\frac{\partial H}{\partial R}
$$
Everything seems fine except one thing. I don't understand how to setup boundary conditions for $\lambda(t)$. Bounds for $R$ are not frozen and not completely free for $R$  since $u$ is not arbitrary.
I would greatly appreciate any help here. Let's omit for now the problem of existence the integral converging etc.

Comment: What value does $k$ have? If it is positive and $R(0)$ is too big, then the saturation constraint on $u$ will result in that $u$ can't drive $R$ to zero. Also what value does $Q$ have, is it positive definite and does it also satisfy $Q \leq 4\,I$?

Comment: I edited $R(0$ and the full post . k is positive and then $R(0)$ is not big since $u(t)$ is bounded. $Q$ is positive diagonal and dimenision of $Q$ is $n$ which can be any number $\e1$